# Clone JIRA task (Клонирование задач Jira)

Tags: python, rest, jira, jira-api

Имеем название задачки в джира, например TES-111
Нужно:

1. Создать клон этой задачи, запомнить его номер. Например, TES-112
2. Переместить новую задачу TES-112 в другой проект, например, SUP. Ей присвоится номер, например, SUP-423. Условие - чтобы в задаче SUP-423 было видно, что она клонирует TES-112.

То есть в веб морде все просто, сначала Clone, потом Move и выбираешь проект.

АПИ для "клонирования" я не нашел. Видимо, нужно запоминать полностью каждую задачу и восстанавливать, не получается это сделать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать это в питоне. Возможно есть более удобные способы.